# SQL in Java Select From Where

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

As part of my assignment I have been asked to retrieve specific data from a database.

However when I try and insert my SQL statement my results wont come back.

I use the variable pcode which has been allocated in a previous class, I know this works as if I remove the single quotes and type postcode (which is the column name) it returns all the results from the database, but I cannot get it to work with my pcode. Below is the code.

```
public static void pcodeSearch(String pcode){

try {
    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/Colin/sale");

    Statement s = c.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sales WHERE postcode = '" + pcode + "';");

    while(rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("street"));
    }
}
catch (SQLException se) {
    se.printStackTrace();
}
```

this is the code the works, this returns all the street names from the database i have created, i never let it run through fully as their are thousands of results but it is clearly establishing a connection with the database ,searching in the table sales and returning information from the colum 'streets'

```
public static void pcodeSearch(String pcode){

try 
{
    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/Colin/sale");

    Statement s = c.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sales;

    while(rs.next())
    {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("street"));

    }
}
catch (SQLException se)
{
    se.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is my main class code, hopefully this helps the context

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            JFrame s = new JFrame("House Sales");


            JButton inst =  new JButton("Instructions");
            JButton close =  new JButton("Close Application");
            JButton go = new JButton("Search");
            JTextField pc = new JTextField(pcode);

            inst.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,80));
            close.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,80));
            go.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,80));
            pc.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,80));

            inst.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(s, "Please enter a full or partial postcode to obtain the sold prices for that area");
                }
            });     

            close.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    s.setVisible(false);
            }
            });     

            go.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    pcode = pc.getText();
                    sqlConnector.pcodeSearch(pcode);
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(s, pcode);
                            }
            });     


            Container c = s.getContentPane();
            c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            c.add(inst);
            c.add(close);
            c.add(pc);
            c.add(go);
            //c.add(t1);


            s.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            s.pack();
            s.setVisible(true);

        }
```

Comment: Can we see the table creation query? And also the result of doing it manually without a WHERE and with a WHERE.

Comment: I would also try to debug the executeQuery line and check what is does the pcode variable hold. Maybe it holds a value which is not present in the db..

Comment: Hi at Maciej, the pcode variable is taken from a textfield in the GUI in my main class, so it varies and i have checked that it is assigning the string correctly using a showMessageDialog and it returns what i typed, the DB itself is correctly linked as i have successfully retrieved street (the street name) using the code without the where statement included.

Comment: Can you attache the executeQuery content when you fill in the pcode manually, without using the variable? .. so the case that works for you.

Comment: to give a bit of context on the whole program, i have a gui with a text field and search button, on click is takes the value of teh text field and stores it in pcode this then searches a database created in sqlite, the problem being that the SQL statment i am using doesnt seem to work, i press the button and it hangs for about 20 seconds then doesnt print the results to teh console. hope this helps clear some stuff up

Answer (score 2):

I would try, and that would be just following good practice anyway, to create a PreparedStatement object and invoke the query this way instead of just passing in the concatenated string:

```
try {
    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/Colin/sale");

     String query = "SELECT street FROM sales WHERE postcode = ?";
     PreparedStatement s = c.prepareStatement(query);
     s.setString(1, pcode);

    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery();

while(rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString("street"));
}
}

catch (SQLException se) {
    se.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also, if you just intent to use the street column, the put it as the only requirement in the Select clause.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thats a great help, and looking through some of the material i have from my lecturer, that is actually the suggested practice, however even with that change the console is still not coming up with any results. for the sake of testing i have only selected street but i will be including more information once i can get the statement to work

Comment: DDL that was used to create the query would be useful to see. Also, when you try to put a different column in the Where statement.. you still have the same problem or is it just that column? And what is exactly the stack trace?